# how to add extra attributes to the quickform before storing it in the database?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have global variable that store the url of the uploaded image by the user.
how do i add that variable as an attribute in the document before adding it to the database?

here is my code

```
Meteor.methods({
    submitPost: function (app) {
        // Console.log('new App:', app);
        check(app, {
            title: String,
            description: String,
            category: String,
            price: Number
        });
        Products.insert(app);
    }

});
```

i want to add the global variable inside "app" before inserting it in Products collection

How do i do it?

This is what i added in the collection

```
previewImage: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function(){
      return PIurl;
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
  createdAt:{
    type: String,
    autoValue: function(){
      return new Date();
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  }
}));
```

after i added the above code, nothing happens when i click on submit, the form is no longer stored in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you can achieve this, the first is to use `AutoForm.hooks` `onSubmit` hook [autoform hooks](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks). The other way is to add it to your schema with the object attribute of `autoValue` :

```
 Schema.something = new SimpleSchema({
     category: {
       type: String,
       autoValue: function () {
        return "foo";
       }
     },
```

Comment: I added your solution and edited my question, after the addition nothing happens when i click on submit, am checking the autoform hooks now :)

Comment: are you using meteor Autoform?

Comment: yes am using it, the form works fine without adding the autoValue field, :)

Comment: thanks its working, i put the date type as string, it should be of Date type, when i changed it, it worked, i accepted your answer, thanks :)